# includes of belongs_to relationship with where clause on joined table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't seem to think through this one. How do I run a where clause off of includes with a `belongs_to` relationship with a wild card?

```
require 'pry'
require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'

connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3',
  database: ":memory:",
  verbosity: 'quiet'
)

class CreateOwners < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:owners) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.date :birthday
    end
  end
end

class CreateDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:dogs) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :owner
    end
  end
end

CreateOwners.new.migrate(:up)
CreateDogs.new.migrate(:up)

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end
```

This throws me an error

```
ar = Dog.includes(:owner).where("owners.birthday < ?", Date.today)
ar.inspect #=>SQLException: no such column: owners.birthday
```

But having a joins before the includes seems to work?

```
ar = Dog.joins(:owner).includes(:owner).where("owners.birthday < ?", Date.today)
ar.inspect #=> [] (which is correct)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumbled upon my answer eventually. It's how `includes` works under the hood by delegating to `preload` or `eager_load`. Here's a good [blog post](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) about it. Includes wasn't detecting the `where` clause being called on the included model so wasn't joining the tables in the query - it was calling `preload` rather than `eager_load` which fires one query and is the same as `joins(:owner).includes(:owner)`

I don't know if this is a bug in AR or my own shallow understanding of AR.

So my query should be:

`Dog.eager_load(:owner).where("owner.birthday < ?", Date.today)`

**Edit:**

So I was off a little. The `eager_load` calls a left outer join which isn't what I wanted - but I was getting lucky because of the where clause. If you want to force an inner join then joins and includes is in fact the correct approach although still feels weird for some reason.

Here's another [resource](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html) which helps clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. I think it's a simple typo in your where.

```
ar = Dog.includes(:owner).where("owner.birthday < ?", Date.today)
```

Comment: So the table name should always be plural in rails / sql land, but just for kicks I tried what you suggested and still nodda. BTW - the code above is completely runnable if you copy paste it into a ruby file and have the necessary gems installed - just in case you wanna play around with it.